# How to use includes function on JSON array

Tags: reactjs, axios

I can't seem to pass the conditional rendering no matter what value I pass into the includes function. The array `freeSlotsList` has values:

0: {id: 1, name: 'MON1', booked: 0, bookedBy: ''}

1: {id: 2, name: 'MON2', booked: 0, bookedBy: ''}

2: {id: 3, name: 'MON3', booked: 0, bookedBy: ''}

3: {id: 4, name: 'MON4', booked: 0, bookedBy: ''}

...

The following code never enters the if statement:

```
    const renderTableData = () => {
    let id = 1;
    const activeButton = () => {};
   
   
    return (
      <tr>
        {days.map((val) => (
          <td>
            {timeSlot.map((n, i) => {
            console.log(freeSlotsList)
              if (freeSlotsList.includes(1) == true) {
                return <h1>Testing</h1>;
              }

              return (
                <button id={id++} className={activeButton}>
                  {n}
                </button>
              );
            })}
          </td>
        ))}
      </tr>
    );
  };
```

The declaration of the useState:

```
   const [freeSlotsList, setFreeSlotsList] = useState([]);
  console.log(freeSlotsList);
  useEffect(() => {

    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/get/week1/ex").then((response) => {
      setFreeSlotsList(response.data);
    });
  }, []);
```

**EDIT:**

it should say:

```
 if (freeSlotsList.includes(id) == true) {
                return <h1>Testing</h1>;
              }
```

Comment: freeSlotsList is an array of objects, how do you expect to find a number within it?

Comment: how do i search for specific id with the includes function?

Comment: Read about the find method of Array.

Comment: As @2184940 methioned if(n.id === 1) should do the trick for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the condition will never be true since the array has only objects. I bet you want to find if some of the objects has the id === 1. In that case you can use `find` or `some`.

```js
freeSlotsList.some(slot => slot.id === id)
```

Comment: My misstake, it should say  ` if (freeSlotsList.includes(id)` I want to compare `freeSlotsList` with `id` which for every iteration increments by one until it reaches 70.  so i want to access the id in the array if that makes sense

Comment: You can replace 1 by the id variable.